# Extract file names from a string

Tags: bash, shell

i have a long string in each line like

> 1000    AS34_59329      RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93     **/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz**        **/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz**        **/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info**
>   11.824  0.981393        43.8283 95.7401 OK

This line contains three file locations (in bold). I need to scp those files to another location like /sample.

How can I use shell to scp files in each line?

```
 while read myline  
  do  
    echo "LINE:"$myline 
    scp .......

  done < datafile.list
```

Comment: I think you might want to check out [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
# grep each file name
$ grep -o "/[^ ]*" datafile.list
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info

# Pipe files to scp 
$ grep -o "/[^ ]*" datafile.list | xargs -i% scp % host:/sample
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. It will try to collect as many files as possible into one `scp` call.

Answer (score 1):

If these are columns 4, 5 and 6, you can do:

```
while read _ _ _ file1 file2 file3 _ 
do  
    scp "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" "user@host:path"
done < datafile.list
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't know you answer. each line contains 3 file locations and other information, i need scp all lines files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the part of your string is a file with `-f` and afterwards do your `scp`.

```
#!/bin/bash
str="1000 AS34_59329 RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93 /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info 11.824 0.981393 43.8283 95.7401 OK"

for i in $str
do
  if [ -f $i ]; then
    echo $i
    # scp here
  fi
done
```

Comment: thanks, i just start learn shell. the i in echo str, i means? it can means any part in str?

Comment: The `echo` is completely useless. Fixed. Also note that this will fail when the file names contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to catch the filenames, that the number of words in a record is variable, and that the filenames don't comprehend spaces (as in your example), you could try this :

```
while read -rd ' ' word || [ "$word" ] ; do
    if [ "$word" != "${word#\/}" ] ; then
        echo '$word is the name of a file'
    fi
done < datafile.list
```